# How to show child div content outside of overflow: hidden parent?

Tags: html, css

I'm using `overflow: hidden;` for parent div. Inside I need to show tooltip, sometime content is bigger in tooltip. This extra content was hidden because of the parent `overflow` property. My code like this:

```
.ui_section {
  overflow: hidden
}
.ui_subsection {
   position: relative
}
.tooltip_section {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translate(-50%, 20px);
}
<div class="ui_section">
  <div class="ui_subsection"></div>
  <div class="tooltip_section"></div>
</div>
```

How can I show tooltip without affecting parent container `overflow: hidden;`?

Comment: You can't do that without changing overflow. But you can achieve it with js.

Comment: What do you need the `overflow:hidden` for if you want the tooltip to grow out of it? Would be kinda hacky to get out of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible if you move the tooltip outside of the `overflow: hidden;` parent. You can create a higher-level parent container that contains both `ui_section` and `tooltip_section` and make them siblings of each other, then your tooltip will be able to appear outside the parent while still getting the correct absolute positioning. Example:

```css
.ui_section {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
.ui_subsection {
   position: relative;
}
.tooltip_section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translate(20px, 20px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui_section_container">
  <div class="ui_section">
    section
    <div class="ui_subsection">
      subsection
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip_section">wide tooltip</div>
</div>
```